# Unable to create Master-Detail relationship where AccountContactRelation is the master

Tags: master-detail, accountcontactrelation

Im creating a master-detail field on a custom object I just created and I was wondering why this standard object (AccountContactRelation) does not appear when I want to select it as the Master...
Thx and sorry for my english in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AccountContactRelation standard object cannot be in Master-Detail relation. Same goes for any other junction object in Salesforce.

> A junction object can't be on the master side of another master-detail relationship.

More to read about relations in SF: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.relationships_considerations.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response and sorry if it was too obvious but I couldnt find any reason on the documentation :D

Comment: @Gatosaurio Have added the link to documentation and cited text from it, you can search for it on docs page and read more about it :)

Comment: Thanks again for being so helpful!! :)